# Node.js Typescript import local files, module not found

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, tsconfig

I compile Typescript to a compile directory called `lib`

And when I import local files from my typescript file, the relative path won't work for the compiled `.js` files, since they are compiled into different directory.

Hence it throws `Error: Cannot find module './email/test.mjml'` Error

```
const text = require("./mytext.txt");
```

How can this be fixed? Is there a way to configure it to fix the import paths when it compiles?

Answer (score 0):

`tsc` has no option to copy non TS files. One solution is to use `copyfiles` as part of your build.

Check out [this blog post](https://vccolombo.github.io/blog/tsc-how-to-copy-non-typescript-files-when-building/) for more info.

Comment: Yes, But is there option to rewrite path references to match the compile directory?

Comment: Path references are for referencing other TS projects, not for static assets. As a general rule, all references to files in `tsconfig.json` are to other TS files. You can try putting your static files inside of `src` then add `include: "*"` to tsconfig. If that doesn't work, either use my answer or use a different build tool.